# Ativar campos em customer/account/create por meio de código

Tags: php, magento

Estou desenvolvendo um módulo onde ele irá alterar o valor do campo `Display Data de Nascimento` e `Ver CPF/CNPJ` em `Configurações> clientes> Configurações> nome e opções de endereço`.

quando esse valor é definido como necessário, ele mostra campos no cadastro de clientes em `customer/account/create`, por isso eu uso o seguinte código em um script de instalação, de modo que quando o módulo é ativado já ativar esses campos que não vêm por padrão.

código:

```
$inchooSwitch = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();

$inchooSwitch->saveConfig('customer/address/dob_show', "req", 'default', '');
$inchooSwitch->saveConfig('customer/address/taxvat_show', "req", 'default', '');
```

alterações de código com sucesso, mas os campos quando eu acesso a página `cliente/conta/criar/` não aparecem.

Alguma idéia de por que isso acontece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu achei a solução vendo o `system.xml` eles usaram um `backend_model` `adminhtml/system_config_backend_customer_show_customer` , que possuía a função `_afterSave` que define o atributo como visível e Obrigatório, segue o código completo depois dos ajustes:

```
<?php

Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('customer/address/dob_show', 'req');
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('customer/address/taxvat_show', 'req');
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('customer/address/gender_show', 'req');

$dobAtribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'dob');
$dobAtribute->setData('is_required', 1);
$dobAtribute->setData('is_visible', 1);
$dobAtribute->save();

$taxvatAtribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'taxvat');
$taxvatAtribute->setData('is_required', 1);
$taxvatAtribute->setData('is_visible', 1);
$taxvatAtribute->save();

$genderAtribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'gender');
$genderAtribute->setData('is_required', 1);
$genderAtribute->setData('is_visible', 1);
$genderAtribute->save();
```